# read arabic chars from mysql using eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, arabic

i have a database which contains an arabic tables , i can read it from Netbeans good so i can see and write arabic chars to the tables but i want to read and write using eclipse, i tried like this:

```
String unicode1 = "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/searchengine"+unicode1, Username, Password);
        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con
                .prepareStatement("select * from invertedindex");
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
        while (results.next()) {
            System.out.println(results.getString(1));
        }
```

but i still see the arabic chars like question marks , what am i doing wrong

**Note:** the tables is support arabic chars because i can read and write to the same table using Netbeans

## EDIT

i tried `System.out.println("يييي");` but i got questions marks , it seems like i have had arabic chars but eclipse doesn't display it

Comment: thank you all , i solve it myself , the answer was to save the editor as UTF-8 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `select convert(name using UTF8) from invertedIndex`

Comment: i got this exception `Unknown character set: 'UTF`

Comment: after editing , i got this exception ` Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'` have i write my tables except Name in the query ?

Comment: after i put my table name like this `select convert(indexTerm using UTF8) from invertedIndex` i got question marks :(

Comment: i wonder why my variable `unicdoe1` works with Netbeans , but doesn't work with Eclipse :(